# How not to resolve a require when using webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack

How would I force webpack not to resolve a require statement in a node module?

In the following unit test example, I would like webpack to resolve `require('./element.js')` but simply to skip `require('chai')`.

How can this be done?

index.js:

```
'use strict';

const assert = require('chai').assert;
const element = require('./element.js');

describe('element.create', function () {
    jsdom();

    it('creates a div', function () {
        var div = document.createElement(element.create());
        assert.strictEqual(div.nodeName, 'DIV');
    });
});
```

Run:

```
webpack index.js index-bundle.js
mocha index-bundle.js
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may be looking for [externals](http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#externals)

from the docs :

> **Externals:** Specify dependencies that shouldn’t be resolved by webpack,
>   but should become dependencies of the resulting bundle. The kind of
>   the dependency depends on output.libraryTarget.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **require.ensure** to load it asynchronously when you needed. This will help you to load *require('chai')* when ever your specific condition is met or do not load.

[require.ensure](https://webpack.github.io/docs/code-splitting.html)

In addition to that to remove the require('chai') from your bundle and to split in to a separate bundle go for vendor bundle 
eg:

```
entry: {
    app: 'entry.js',
    vendor: ['jquery', 'jquery.plugin1']
}
```